# how to add multiple values in shared preferences android

Tags: android

I have shared preference . I want to store multiple values that are present on the listview .

I am getting the data but not full data .

The code is present in the base adapter and kindly please help me i am running out of time .

```
Map<String, String> nameIcons = new HashMap<String, String>();
    nameIcons.put("publisheddate",publisheddate);
    nameIcons.put("validity",validity);
    nameIcons.put("accessstatus",accessstatus);

      settings=ctxt.getSharedPreferences("com.contentraven",0);
      editor=settings.edit();

      editor.clear();
      editor.commit();
      for (String s : nameIcons.keySet()) 
      {
          editor.putString(s, nameIcons.get(s));
      }

      editor.commit();
```

Comment: Change index as nameIcons.get(S) and value as s.

Comment: Elaborate what kind of data you get and what you expect to get. Also include the reading part of the code. With this code you will only save 3 entries in total.

Comment: Why don't you try to save them as a List ? And why dont you get all list data from where list is loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ..

```
//For storing
      Map<String, String> nameIcons = new HashMap<String, String>();
      nameIcons.put("publisheddate",publisheddate);
      nameIcons.put("validity",validity);
      nameIcons.put("accessstatus",accessstatus);
      SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.contentraven",0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); 
      editor.clear();
      editor.commit();

      for (String s : nameIcons.keySet()) {
         editor.putString(s, map.get(s));
      }
      editor.commit();          

// for loading            
       SharedPreferences pref =   getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.contentraven",0);
       HashMap<String, String> map= (HashMap<String, String>) pref.getAll();
       int i=0;
       String val[]=new String[map.size()]; 
       for (String s : map.keySet()) {
            val[i]=map.get(s);

           i++;
        }
```